# Java Android internet Access: WIFI or 3G

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-intent, android-service

In my android application it has to access a remote server to send a request and to receive the response to continue the functionality.

I need to clarify that before send the request, do I have to specially select that it should be WIFI or Mobile(3G) Internet in a situation where both available. I am not sure that ANDROID OS itself will select the best among them Or will give an exception in runtime. I can't test it as I am working with emulator. Would like to know the standard way.

I can check whether it has connected with WIFI or 3G(Mobile) by the following code. Like to know before I send the request if I have to select that it should be WIFI or MOBILE(3G) internet. A proper guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance...

```
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

   for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) 
   {
       if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI") && ni.isConnected())
       {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to Internet with WIFI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE") && ni.isConnected())
       {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to Internet with 3G", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> do I have to specially select that it should be WIFI or Mobile(3G) Internet in a situation where both available

The OS handles this. If there is a known and configured WiFi access point available, Android will use it.

More importantly, you *can't* "select" it yourself. You get what the OS gives you.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare... If ANDROID OS Handles this then thats fine. I was wondering if any exception situation will occur.. Thanks. I will continue...

Answer (score 2):

---

### The OS handles this. If there is a known and configured WiFi access point available, Android will use it.

That is true. I just wanted to verify this by running your code, so I did this and the results are.

Steps:

1. Ensure Wifi is on and connected.
2. Ensure Mobile(3G) network is on.
3. Execute your code above

Results:
 android chooses wifi instead of mobile(3g)